# Docker - Can't resolve node module in '/usr/src/app/src'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm

I have this `docker`service:

```
client/
      .dockerignore
      Dockerfile-dev
      package.json
      node_modules/
                  react-router-dom/   
                  spotify-web-api-js/
                  and-many-more/
      src/  
         App.jsx
         Spotify.js
```

which installs the following `node` modules:

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "spotify-web-api-js": "^0.22.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1"
  }
}
```

like so:

> Dockerfile-dev

```
# base image
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.2 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

at the same path, `src`, however, I'm observing two different behaviours:

1) this works:

> App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

2) but this does not work:

> Spotify.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';   
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-js';
```

throwing the following error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/Spotify.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'spotify-web-api-js' in '/usr/src/app/src'
```

> docker-compose-dev.yml

```
  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3007:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web
```

> .dockerignore

```
node_modules
coverage
build
env
htmlcov
.dockerignore
Dockerfile-dev
Dockerfile-prod
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Is that your full Dockerfile ? It looks like you have not copied your src files.

Comment: yes, it is. what else should I do?

Comment: I mean you have not copied your src/* to the docker. `COPY src/* .` after `npm install` statement, but I am not sure if this is causing the issue.

Comment: lets try that..

Comment: `ERROR: Service 'client' failed to build: When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /`

Comment: Sry replace with `COPY src .`.

Comment: nope. same error persists....

Comment: I've edited the quesiton with `docker-compose-dev.yml`.

Comment: Best to create `.dockerignore` file at the level of `Dockerfile` and add `node_modules` in that file. After that you are safe to copy everything from your local folder to docker image by just doing `COPY . .`. Please see here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: .dockerignore was there already, forgot to mention, sorry

Answer (score 6):

Hope this helps someone it works for me run

```
docker-compose down -v
```

It removes all volumes.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say how long I spent reinstalling modules and even NPM / Node entirely. In the end it turned out I had around 100 previous volumes still running in the background. This command fixed my issue - many thanks for sharing

Comment: Not sure why this answer has not accepted yet, While it works.